# Central authentication with Samba4 for applications

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, samba4

I have a small problem / doubt about the use of Samba4 as a central authenticator of external applications, I explain, I am instantiating a Samba4 server as a PDC for domain authentication for some computers with W10, but already taking advantage of it I wanted to configure it as a central authenticator for applications .

In many applications I see that they allow LDAP / AD connection, but it is not clear to me if it differs between LDAP and Active Directory, may it be necessary to use Samba4 in combination with OpenLDAP as a backend to authenticate applications? Or can only Samba4 be used for everything?

After trying to authenticate the logins of the applications through Samba4 (PHPIPAM, NextCloud, Proxmox, Nagios) I have only achieved a good user authentication in Proxmox, the other applications give me many problems.

In summary, someone who has experience configuring central authentication environments can clarify how I can mount the server and if I have to do it using Samba4 and LDAP, or only Samba4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

samba4 is able to run as an AD domain controller (see https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller).

You should not need to use openldap and samba4 for different applications, configuring the applications to use samba4 as their ldap server should suffice.

As to the problems you are experiencing with some applications, well, yes, I believe you are having them. You do not indicate any details of what you have tried and problems you had when trying what you did, so nobody can help you.